# How Can I find the subdomains of a specific domain or ip address In Java?

Tags: java, security, dns, enumeration

How can I find the subdomains of a specific domain without brute force using java.

I used the WhoisClient in my code but It gave me errors.

```java
public static List<String> enumerateSubdomains(String domain) {
    List<String> subdomains = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        WhoisClient whoisClient = new WhoisClient();
        whoisClient.setDefaultTimeout(100000);
        whoisClient.connect(WhoisClient.DEFAULT_HOST);

        String whoisData = whoisClient.query("=" + domain);
        whoisClient.disconnect();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Domain Name: (.+?)\\.");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(whoisData);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            subdomains.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return subdomains;
}
```

Comment: What type of errors did it give?